# Multiply a list of ints using list comprehension

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

Is there a way to do this with list comprehension?

```
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    if i == 0:
        sum = x[i]
    else:
        sum = sum * x[i]
```

I've tried this:

```
[total for i in x if i == 0 total = x[i] else total = total * x[i]]
```

and this:

```
[total = x[i] if i == 0 else total = total * x[i] for i in x]
```

I saw that there is a way to do it with `enumerate` but I was wondering if there is a way to do it in one line just using list comprehension. I'm not trying to solve a problem, I'm just curious.

Comment: You can't (sensibly) modify variables in a list comprehension, so this is not possible

Comment: `sum` is a really bad name for a product...

Comment: @Eric lol, yeah I realized that at changed it to product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna prefix this with "you do not want to do this". No really. But if you did...

```
# whatever your input is
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# set the initial total to 1, and wrap it in a list so we can modify it in an expression
total = [1]

# did I mention you shouldn't do this?
[total.__setitem__(0, xi * total.__getitem__(0)) for xi in x]

print total[0]
120
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I wouldn't want to do that, it's totally not readable. I was just wondering if it's possible. I got down-voted for my curiosity, YAY!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is `reduce`, but not list comprehension.

```
from operator import mul
s = [1, 2, 3]
print reduce(mul, s, 1)
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
class Mul(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.product = 1
    def __call__(self, x):
        self.product *= x
        return self.product

s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
m = Mul()
[m(x) for x in s]
```

Comment: Thanks. I know there are ways to do it without the if-else, I'm specifically asking if it could be done only using list comprehension. I guess I'm trying to find out if there is anyway to access the index in list comprehension.

Comment: `["first" if i == 0 else "rest" for i, value in enumerate(x)]` will let you access the index